# How to load localStorage value using fetch() on page load?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have 2 html pages, `index.html` and `dropdown-component.html`

`dropdown-component.html`:

```html
<select id="AssistSelectMenu">
  <option value="assist/AK.html">Alaska</option>
  <option value="assist/AL.html">Alabama</option>
  <option value="assist/AZ.html">Arizona</option>
</select>
```

`onclick` of a button in `index.html`, I try to fetch the content of `dropdown-component.html`

Using the ff:

```js
function fetchJXSelectMenu() {
fetch('dropdown-component.html')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => document.querySelector('#component-assist-jx-select-menu').innerHTML = text);
}
```

It is loaded in a div `<div id="component-assist-jx-select-menu"></div>`.

The problem is, the "component" it loads is a `select/option` that utilizes localStorage to remember the last selected option of the user.

It looks like this:

```js
$(function () {
    $('#AssistSelectMenu').change(function () {
        localStorage.setItem('JXselect', this.value);
    });
    if (localStorage.getItem('JXselect')) {
        $('#AssistSelectMenu').val(localStorage.getItem('JXselect'));
    }
});
```

If I'm not using the `fetch()` method, the `localStorage` function works fine, but if I do use it, it fails to load the last selected option of the user on page load. I'm guessing this is because the browser has already finished rendering the page and can't process the `localStorage` for the newly loaded component.

So my question is how do I workaround this? I tried putting the script in the component but that didn't solve it at all.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Without seeing some HTML it's a bit hard to understand. After a second look, I cannot see any code where you're setting your SELECT value (by reading it from LocalStorage) after populating your HTML... Its not even clear what you're populating it with exactly.

Comment: I will update it right away, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: The change listener will not receive a trigger until the new element is changed. So, I think you will need to populate the select element with options retrieved from local storage before adding it to the document. This would therefore have to be done in the last `.then` argument of your fetch block.